# Compose a custom spring annotation with a parameter?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-amqp

is it possible to turn this annotation

```
@RabbitListener(
    bindings = [QueueBinding(
        key = [Amqp.FOLEY_NEW],
        value = Queue(Amqp.FOLEY_NEW),
        exchange = Exchange(name = "amq.topic", type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC  )
    )]
)
```

into a custom annotation that simply takes the queue name as a parameter?

giving this a go, but I don't see that I can reference `Listener.value`

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention
@RabbitListener(
    bindings = [QueueBinding(
        key = [Amqp.FOLEY_NEW],
        value = Queue(Amqp.FOLEY_NEW),
        exchange = Exchange(name = "amq.topic", type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC  )
    )]
)
annotation class Listener( val value: String )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to work because a custom annotation must refer somehow to the meta-annotation. The `@RabbitListener` doesn't have a `value()` attribute. Although you can try with an `@AliasFor`. See its JavaDocs for more info.

Nevertheless I'm not sure in your goal. You declare a `@RabbitListener` with some `bindings` and its result is going to be used in the target listener container. Any additional queues (e.g. via `queues()`) are going to be used in the container as well, even if you will be able to achieve design with the `@AliasFor`. Is that what you expect?